# Probability of Sampling without Replacement

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Let $Y_1, Y_2, \dots , Y_{10}$ be a random unordered sample without replacement from the set $\{1, \dots, 100\}$.
(This means that the numbers $Y_1, \dots, Y_{10}$ are not necessarily ordered.)

(a) What is the probability that $|Y_1 − Y_2| = 1$?

(b) Let $Z$ be the number of indices $1 ≤ k ≤ 9$ with $|Y_k − Y_{k+1}| = 1$. (E.g. if the sample is
$3, 1, 4, 5, 11, 14, 13, 99, 43, 72$ then $Z = 2$.) Find $\mathbb E[Z]$.
Hint: part (a) should help.

So my rationale for this problem was that the numbers have to be right next to one another, so then I used the complement,

$\Pr(\text{$Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are next to one another}) = 1 - \Pr(\text{$Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are not next to one another})
= 1 - (99/100 * 98/100) = .0298$

Is that the right way to do it?

And then for part b I am not sure what formula to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

for question **a)**
$$P(|Y_{1}-Y_{2}|=1)=\sum P(|i-Y_{2}|=1/Y_{1}=i)P(Y_{1}=i)$$
$$=\sum P(|i-Y_{2}|=1) \frac {1}{100}$$
$$=\frac {2}{99}\frac {1}{100}+\frac {98*2}{99}\frac {1}{100}=\frac{1}{50}$$

for question **b)**

You can see your variable $Z$ as :
$$Z=\sum \mathbb{1}_{|Y_k-Y_{k+1}|=1}$$
Hence $$\mathbb{E}(Z)=\sum \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{1}_{|Y_k-Y_{k+1}|=1}) =\sum P(|Y_k-Y_{k+1}|=1) $$ ...

Answer (score 0):

Wrong answer for (a).  For $2\le Y_1\le 99$, $Y_2$ has two possible values, so probability here is $=\frac{98}{100}\times\frac{2}{99}$.  For the two end point values of $Y_1$, $Y_2$ has one possible value with sum probability $=\frac{2}{100}\times \frac{1}{99}$.  Total probability $=.02$.

Comment: (a) corrected: For (b)  I believe it is $9\times .02=.18$.